# Ping source interface "ping: invalid source address eth0:1"

Tags: kali-linux

I have this problem, I have assigned an IP address to my `eth0` interface, I would like to assign an IP address in the `eth0: 1` interface.

Now I try to ping with `source eth0: 1` but it returns this error:

```
ping -I eth0:1 <IP address>

ping: invalid source address eth0:1

ping -I <IP eth0:1> <IP address>

ping: unknown iface**
```

How can I fix it?

I rewrite my problem:
Sorry but I do not know how to use the site. I tell you what to do, I would like to simulate the traffic created by an external entity. My Laptop has only one network adapter configured with an IP/30 attached to a Firewall, what I would like to do is configure another card (eth0:1 or Lo:xx) with an IP/24. In this way I would like to simulate virtual source traffic with the source. Can this be done? Thank you

Comment: What is the eth0: 1 interface?

Comment: Can you show your interface list with `ip a`? If your interface name is `eth0: 1`, you might need to add a quote around it.

Comment: @JohnKoch First of all it'd never be formatted like that, second even if it was ping still wouldn't work with that syntax.

Comment: `eth0:1` (no space) is the old way before the current `ip` tool to indicate multiple IPv4 addresses. Make sure you don't use a space. You can also use `ping -I 1.2.3.4` with the source address, it will pick the correct interface (and it will pick `eth0` anyway as `eth0:1` and `eth0` are the same interface).

Comment: You can edit [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/406203/edit) to add more information.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how to use the site.
I tell you what to do, I would like to simulate the traffic created by an external entity.
My Laptop has only one network adapter configured with an IP/30 attached to a Firewall, what I would like to do is configure another card (eth0:1 or Lo:xx) with an IP/24.

In this way I would like to simulate virtual source traffic with the source.
Can this be done?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to U&L , [You can edit your question by clicking on this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/406203/edit)